# Vue.js 1.0 method not firing on change select

Tags: javascript, select, onchange, vue.js

Following Vue.js 1.0 [examples](http://vuejs.org/guide/forms.html#Select), I've made a select dropdown with v-model project, like this:

```
{{ project }}
<select class="projects" v-model="project" @change="changeProject">
    <option value="1">School</option>
    <option value="2">Personal</option>
    <option value="3">Work</option>
</select>
```

The js bit:

```
new Vue({
    el: '#main',
    data: {
        project: ''
    },
    methods: {
        changeProject: function(){
            console.log(this.project);
        }
    }
});
```

The tag `{{ project }}` is displaying correctly, but when I select another value on the select dropdown it doens't fires the method `changeProject`.

What am I missing here?

Cheers.

**EDIT:**

After @mustafo's answer, I tried to create a simple button with a @click method and it print the value. Only the @change on this select isn't working.

**EDIT2:**

I've realised why this is not working. I'm changing the selected option of this select box with an jquery function, because I needed to create a full css styled dropdown, and then I created a "mask" for it.

Comment: but it is working. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nnbr214c/)

Comment: strange... on mine isn't. Although a simple @click on a button is working.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, I've run into this issue as well. The proper solution according to me is add `v-model` to select tag and then add watching of that model into `watch` object:

```
watch: {
    myModel: function(currentValue) {

        // do my stuff
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Seems like your version of vue.js does not support shorthands. Try `v-on:change="..."` instead of `@change="..."`

Comment: thanks for your answer @mustafo. I've tried that way, but its still not working